# Appending data from AJAX .each() loop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I'm trying to emulate what http://www.forecast.io does with their daily forecast, you can click on the line for each day and get more detailed information in a slidedown() box that shows sunrise time, sunset time, etc.

I'm using Ajax and .each() to retrieve my data in jsonp format.  I have my click handler inside my .each() loop because I need to access variables that store the information from each day.  I know I need to listen for the click and append the information outside of the each loop, but I will not have access to the variables that are stored locally in the .each() loop if I set my functionality outside the loop.

The html I'm trying to append is...

```
var forecastData = 
            '<ul class="box hide">' +
            '<li>SUNRISE: ' + sunriseTime + '</li>' +
            '<li>SUNSET: ' + sunsetTime + '</li>' +
            '<div class="box-second-line">' +
            '<li>LOW: ' + forecastMin + ' @' + minTempTime + '</li>' +
            '<li>HIGH: ' + forecastMax + ' @' + maxTempTime + '</li>' +
            '</ul></div><br><br>';
```

These data in these variables are coming from jsonp in the .each() loop.

<strike>How can I append the information for each individual day outside the each loop?</strike>

<strike>I've added this...</strike>

```
//Click event to show more forecast data
             $(document).on('click', '.forecast-list', function () {
                        $(this).next('.forecast-data').append(forecastData);
                });
```

...inside the .each() loop, and am now appending the information I want.  The issue now is when I click on a day all the data for all 7 days of the future forecast are being added simultaneously.  I need to single out each individual day, so that when the element for e.g. Tuesday is click, only the data for Tuesday day is added.

I've gotten my click handler to append the proper information for each day but no I'm having issues with the toggle function.

My new click handler is as follows...

```
 //Click event to unhide hidden forecast data
            $(document).on('click', '.forecast-list', function () {
                $(this).next($('.box')).slideToggle();
            });
```

The toggle action isn't working properly though, it just 'bounces' open and closed 4 times and then stays shut.  Is this because the toggle is inside the .each() loop?

Here's my code pen for the project.  http://codepen.io/DDD37/pen/GozGGx

Comment: I would probably keep the HTML constant string somewhere outside and read the data in some kind of array of data. Then I would have a function which formulates to object into the string you need. So you could call `formatStr(forecastData[1])`, `formatStr(forecastData[2])`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By moving ...

```
 //Click event to unhide hidden forecast data
            //Create a function that combines both the fade and toggle effects
            $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (speed, easing, callback) {
                return this.animate({
                    opacity: 'toggle',
                    height: 'toggle'
                }, speed, easing, callback);
            };

            //Listen to the document(the elements are created dynamically) for click on the forecasts to invoke
            //the slideFadeToggle function
            $(document).on('click', '.forecast-list', function () {
                $(this).next($('.box')).slideFadeToggle('6000', 'linear');
            });
```

...outside the `.each()` loop, but still insdie the `.ajax` call, got it working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question. You need to access JSON data from outside of ajax success function.

just store JSON data in data attribute of any control and then you can find same JSON data later.

Add a div tag in side your page

```
<div id="forecast" style="display:none" data-futureforecast=""></div>
```

And JS file

```
$.ajax({
url: apiURL,
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(json) {
$('div#forecast').data('futureforecast',json);
//----
your code
//--
}
});
```

now you can find you data later

```
var forecastData= $('div#forecast').data('futureforecast');
```

Comment: The issue I ran into with setting the display to none is that when the element are created, it leaves a blank space where the json data is being hidden.  I want the effect where when the user clicks the element, the hidden information is added with the slideDown effect so that all the descendant elements are pushed down to 'make room' for the newly appended data.